# Including Grails Plugin Source in Grails 1.3.5 project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I want to use a snapshot version of the grails quartz plugin. The issue is, I want to be able to specify the dependency or include the source of the plugin in my project so that my coworkers and our build server don't have to download the plugin's zip file themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by connecting to the plugin's repository through an svn:external, and then adding the following to my BuildConfig.groovy.

```
grails.plugin.location."quartz" = "path/to/svn/external"
```